How to visualise Kmeans clusters when using cooccurrence matrices?
I am trying to cluster words using Kmeans. I have one large document and I use an NLTK RegexpTokenizer first and then filter based on word count, length and remove stopwords. Next, I construct a co-occurrence matrix and use this to train the Kmeans model. Finally, I test the performance of this using silhouette scores.
I would like to visualise these clusters. This typically seems to be done using a scatter plot and the labels. How do I reduce this co-occurrence matrix to x and y, when it is currently an N x N matrix (N is the number of unique words)? I have tried using PCA:
plt.figure()
pca_2d = PCA(n_components=2)
reduced = pca_2d.fit_transform(mat)
newKm = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
labels = newKm.fit_predict(reduced)
plt.scatter(reduced[:, 0], reduced[:, 1], c=labels) # selects column 0 (all rows) as x coords and column 1 (all rows) as y. and then cluster labels.
plt.title("K-means Clustering")
plt.show()

But am not sure if this is the best or correct approach?

Using the co-occurence matrix as word representations + PCA later on to reduce dimensionality for K means is a fine approach.
Some improvements you can consider can be

Using word embeddings instead of a co-occurence matrix (from a model like Word2Vec trained or fine tuned on your documents) as this can give you a richer representation of words
Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters in k means, or (usually preferably) Silhouette clustering
For dimensionality reduction, PCA is efficient but is known to preserve global structure. An alternative would be t-SNE which preserve local structure. This is explained well in this answer. Or U-map which can help balance between local and global structure.

